# $f'(x)=(3/x)-4; (1,0)$ derivative at a specific point

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

So I have been trying to figure out how to do this type of problem for quite a while now.

Question States:

The slope $f'(x)$ at each point $(x,y)$ on a curve $y=f(x)$  is given along with a particular point $(a, b)$ on the curve. Use this information to find $f(x)$.
$$
f'(x)=\frac{3}{x}-4\quad\text{ at } (1,0)
$$
I would appreciate it greatly if someone could explain how to go about this problem or point me in the right direction. My textbook instructions are confusing me greatly on this particular problem.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Try integrating $f'(x)$ as an indefinite integral, then using the condition that the curve goes through the point $(1,0)$ to find your integration constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $f'(x)=\frac 3x - 4$: take the indefinite integral of each side to get

$$f(x)=3\ln x -4x+C$$

where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

Now you find the value of the constant by substituting the known values of $x$ and $f(x)$ from your given point $(1,0)$: $f(1)=0$, so

$$0=3 \ln 1 -4 \cdot 1 + C$$
$$C=4$$

So your final formula for $f(x)$ is

$$f(x)=3\ln x -4x+4$$

You should check this on a graphing calculator, program, or web page.

Comment: @JerichoDefeated Please accept the answer if you got what you were looking for so that others don't waste their time and post answer again. :)

Comment: @lsp Will do, just got back to my computer and haven't had a chance to try solution yet.

Comment: @Rory Daulton Thanks for your fast reply and your help. I believe I understand what I'm doing now.